# Export multiple sheets into one csv file excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel workbook with 10 sheets , I want to export range "B17:H28" from each sheet into one
csv file not multiple csv files .I have code which exports each sheet with range into multiple csv files.

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Set rngtemp = Sheet.Range("B17:H28")
rngtemp.Copy
csvfilenametemp= ....
Set wbtemp = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
With wbtemp
.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.SaveAs Filename:=csvfilenametemp, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
.Close
End With
```

Comment: Copy all of the ranges into *one* sheet in a new workbook and then save as CSV.

Comment: BigBen can you give me an example how to update to the last row so I wont repaste existing rows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple csv files into one file by

1. opening command prompt
2. Go to where your file is stored using `cd "C/..."`
3. Type `copy *.csv to output.csv`
4. Press run and check your directory